# CSS Change button image on click

Tags: html, css

I have two HTML image buttons (both are grey color), and whenever user clicks on any button I have to change grey color image to color image (I have 2 color images) and make other button grey. So user can know the active button.

How can I achieve this in CSS?

Comment: I think you need javascript and optional css to do this

Comment: You'll need javascript for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add .button class (for example) to the buttons then use this jQuery code:

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
  $('.button' ).removeClass('active');
  $( this ).addClass('active');
});

<input type="button" class="button" id="button1" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" class="button" id="button2" value="Button 2">
```

Then with CSS you set the colors.
You can have as many buttons as you want. See the fiddle below to check how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to use something like:

```
function buttonOnClick(){
$("#button2").css("background-color","Green");
}

<input type="button" onClick="buttonOnClick()">
<input type="button" id="button2">
```

Comment: It's more complex than that, he/she wants two buttons that behave like the `radio` inputs.

Comment: what if I have more than 10 buttons, do I have to write it for 10 times ?
exactly @vikki

Comment: OK, got it. See @Alfonso Jiménez answer, he posted it before I properly edited my code to fit your request.